# Плагин для сохранения частей кода в OBSIDIAN для Python, или иные способы создания заметок

Tags: python, плагин

Скажите, какой плагин нужно добавить в  OBSIDIAN, чтобы можно было удобно сохранять куски кода в виде заметок? Нашел только JUPYTER, но не пойму, как настроить, вроде путь к интерпретатору прописал, никаких предупреждений/ошибок программа не пишет, но и не делает ничего.

P.S.: может плохо гуглил, но внятного ответа не нашел, наверняка есть иные способы хранения кода в виде заметок, буду благодарен за советы

Comment: Просто стандартными средствами markdown в текст вставляйте: https://www.markdownguide.org/extended-syntax/#fenced-code-blocks

Comment: Спасибо, как вариант. Но попался вот такой способ на ютюб (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8WZj7JNjsp8&t=22s&ab_channel=DanDelobo) и что то не могу найти, как осуществить

Comment: @rise, спасибо. Благодаря тебе, или вам, как будет угодно, я заразился обсидианом, скачал и уже пишу в нём. Про плагин ничего не знаю, но спасибо за программу для написания заметок

Comment: Пожалуйста) Вот и я "заразился", только местами ума дать не могу. Плагин я нашел, путь и зависимости настроил, а код не работает в нем

Comment: т.е. ты прямо в обсидиане хочешь запускать код ? А как же отладка. Обсидиан подходит для сохранения кода, но всё же он не подходит для запуска. Есть бесплатная программа `PyCharm` для запуска кода

Comment: @rise, `Но попался вот такой способ на ютюб (youtube.com/…) и что то не могу найти, как осуществить` так это вообще не обсидиан, а Visual Studio Code. Просто открываете в нем папку, устанавливайте плагин Python и запускаете то что вам нужно. P.S. точнее, слева VSCode открыт, справа Obsidian. И я не увидел, чтобы там что-то интегрировалось между собой, просто он одновременно в двух программах работает.

Comment: "т.е. ты прямо в обсидиане хочешь запускать код ? "Фрагменты кода, я только изучаю , поэтому использую обсидиан, как хранилище основных знаний. Посмотри Ютюб ссылку, под первым ответом. Там как раз пример такого взаимодействия

Comment: @rise, я не увидел там особого взаимодействия, ну либо нужно прямо всматриваться. Код он запускает в vscode.

Comment: Да не суть даже в этом, просто этот плагин о котором речь должен работать , как облегченный редактор кода внутри обсидиан. https://github.com/tillahoffmann/obsidian-jupyter верно я понимаю?

Comment: Это встраивание jupyter в obsidian видимо. Это не облегченный редактор кода. Код можно редактировать и без него.

Comment: Да именно так, я видимо не до конца прочитал информацию с гитхаба. Там надо ещё скрипт создать и сохранить внутри плагина вроде как. Хотя можно и забить на это, ответ вы уже дали. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Куски кода в программе Obsidian сохраняются так

```
~~~python
import os
Obsidian = 'c:/users/os/Obsidian'
os.mkdir( Obsidian )
~~~
```